# how to redirect any domain name to our web application

Tags: dns, saas

we have a saas web app, written in zend mvc (php) where users can enter their own domain name in their settings page.

When they enter e.g. www.customdomain.com we want this domain to redirect to our web application so we can serve up their own pages from our app.

We do the same already for subdomains by having a *.ourapp.com entry in our DNS configuration.
that works great for subdomains like customdomain.ourapp.com.

This doesn't seem to work for full domain names like www.customdomain.com.

What's the easiest way to have any domain address link to our application, so we can just read out the incoming domain name and act accordingly in our app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For letting the DNS entry point at your servers:

- Domain is already registered (and owned by the customer): Make him configure the CNAME entry to your server's IP. (Even google let this do the enduser by hand - so automating this might be hard)
- Domain is free: Register it, configure the CNAME yourself (you own it)

If you only want a redirect, the user can upload a html file or .htaccess file, that performs the redirect. But this has to be done by the customer, too.